# How to match a 10-char string ending with 2 Digits?

Tags: regex

I have a list of Strings in this form

```
1:nlcbjduy14 <- I want regex to find this one 
2:Peoples123 <- I don't want regex to find this one, as it has 3 digits.
3:sqourzyr17 <- I want regex to find this one
4:rdmaszgr94 <- I want regex to find this one
5:tnwiudic22 <- I want regex to find this one
6:zfcxmkrs21 <- I want regex to find this one
7:xrwhsgno55 <- I want regex to find this one
8:modtwtrr06 <- I want regex to find this one
9:People123  <- I don't want regex to find this one, as it is isn't 10 chars long and it consists of 3 digits.
10:aetmyqqh52 <- I want regex to find this one
11:Howtocodelikeapro12 <- I don't want regex to find this one, as it is isn't 10 chars long
12:netphvib58 <- I want regex to find this one
13:uwyiqhoj29 <- I want regex to find this one
14:RegexJustiIsntDoingItForMe
15:qyeiaecj27 <- I want regex to find this one
16:buttercake <- I don't want regex to find this one, as it doesn't end with 2 digits.
17:bcyiyjdm23 <- I want regex to find this one
18:Differings <- I don't want regex to find this one, as it doesn't end with 2 digits.
```

What I'm looking for, is some kind of regex to replace all 10-character strings which end with max. 2 digits.

After replacing those strings, it would look like this:

```
1:REPLACED
2:Peoples123
3:REPLACED
4:REPLACED
5:REPLACED
6:REPLACED
7:REPLACED
8:REPLACED
9:People123
10:REPLACED
11:Howtocodelikeapro12
12:REPLACED
13:REPLACED
14:RegexJustiIsntDoingItForMe
15:REPLACED
16:buttercake
17:REPLACED
18:Differings
```

Could anyone give me an example of a regex that would work?
I couldn't find any other (understandable) questions about this on Stackoverflow, as I am not very familiar with regex. I'm trying to match these in Notepad++, not in any programming language.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is context, that you are using regular expressions in? Can you please name the programming language or IDE?

Comment: Hi, Sorry that I didn't clarify this. I am using it in Notepad++/Emeditor.

Comment: Try this regex: \D{8}\d{2}, this should do you a job for you.  https://regex101.com/r/u80Q9O/1

Comment: What about som1user23? 10 characters with a digit in the middle?

Answer (score 2):

Well, without knowing what flavor you're using (If it's PHP or python, e.t.c) it's a bit harder to give you an answer but try this:

```
\d+:\D{8}\d{2}
```

I strongly recoomend you to take some time studying Regex since it is a powerful tool.

If you want to understand this regex and learn a little bit more, go [here](https://regex101.com/r/jipoMt/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: This will only match the text after the `#:`

```
(?<=\:)\D{8}\d{2}\b
```

- `(?<=\:)` - positive look behind for the `:` character
- `\D{8}` - exactly 8 non-digits
- `\d{2}` - exactly 2 digits
- `\b` - word boundary (end of word)

Use this and you can maintain your numbers, but replace the Usernames

Answer (score 0):

I think this RegEx works:

```
:\D{8}\d{2}\D
```

It consists of : as it is the begining of your strings. Then we have 8 not-digit characters, 2 digit characters and something that is not a digit to prevent too long numbers. It follows PCRE standard, so it should work with your editor Notepad++.

Comment: Hi! Just tried it and seems to be almost correct. When I tried this, it did indeed remove what I wanted to remove, but it also replaced other strings. For example: kgcqvuxn32 
manuela71343606
tcbcbzcn93 became this:                                                                                          
    - REPLACED
    - REPLACED43606 <- String contained 15 characters, but was still matched.
    - REPLACED

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [Link to Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QiFL3L/2)

```regex
\W([A-Za-z]{8}\d{2})\W
```

---

**Explanation**

1. `\W` - Matches any character that is neither alphanumerical nor underscore
2. `\W(...)\W` - The group in parenthesis is the thing we desire. It is a string that is surrounded by neither alphanumerical nor underscore. Let's call it "word".
3. `[A-Za-z]{8}` - A consecutive string of letters with the exact length 8.
4. `\d{2}` - Exactly two consecutive digits.

---

I am not sure about Notepad++, but in most cases you can get the first group with `$1`. The zero-th group would be the whole match.